# Do I need to start vim with sudo?

Tags: vim

When I start vim with `$ vim` the changes I made to `.vimrc` are not in effect; but when I start with `$ sudo vim` the changes are in effect. What is the cause of this? Do I need to start vim with `sudo` always?

Answer (score 1):

system files that require elevated privileges will require sudo, otherwise you wouldn't need it. .vimrc is likely to be a essential system or program file. Just like how you would need sudo to alter any of your roor files in /etc/~ and whatnot.

Comment: But when I start vim without sudo as `$ vim` my changes to .vimrc are not effected. Why is this? For instance, the default in .vimrc is 6 spaces for tab, I changed that to 4 spaces, but when I start vim with `$ vim` 8 tabs are there not 4 tabs.

Comment: .vimrc is a product of a application in /usr/bin (which is a system)